# Convert keys to Values

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, treemap, keyset

I'm trying to convert the keys of a Map to Values of another Map, but finally only one key was return as Value. What was the problem?
when the program excuted I got different Result

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;

        public class KeystoValues {

            public static void KtoV(Map<Double, Integer> Key) {
                

                Map<Double, Integer> List = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
                Map<Integer, Double> KeystoV = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
                
                System.out.println("List Map\n");
                
                List.putAll(Key);
                for(Map.Entry<Double, Integer> val : List.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(val.getKey() + "," + val.getValue());
                }
                    
                for(int h = 1; h<=List.size(); h++)
                    for(Map.Entry<Double, Integer> convert : List.entrySet()) {
                        Double j = convert.getKey();
                        KeystoV.put(h, j);
                    }   
                
                System.out.println("\nSet of keys in List Map now converted to set "
                        + "of Values and stored to KeystoV Map\n\nKeystoV Map\n");
                
                for(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> converted : KeystoV.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(converted.getKey() + "," + converted.getValue());
                }
                
                
            }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                ArrayList<Integer> Value = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                Map<Double, Integer> Key = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
                
                Key.put(45.0,1);
                Key.put(40.0,2);
                Key.put(23.0,2);
                Key.put(25.0,3);
                Key.put(0.0,1);
                
                KtoV(Key);
                
            }

        }
```

List Map

```
                0.0,1
                25.0,3
                40.0,2
                45.0,1
                23.0,2
```

Set of keys in List Map now converted to set of Values and stored to KeystoV Map

KeystoV Map

```
                1,23.0
                2,23.0
                3,23.0
                4,23.0
                5,23.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is this nested for loop:

```
        for(int h = 1; h<=List.size(); h++)
            for(Map.Entry<Double, Integer> convert : List.entrySet()) {
                Double j = convert.getKey();
                KeystoV.put(h, j);
            }
```

If you debug it, then you'll see that you are always putting the last iterated value of List.entrySet() as the value of all keys.

Try changing it to:

```
int index = 1;
for (Map.Entry<Double, Integer> convert : List.entrySet()) {
    KeystoV.put(index, convert.getKey());
    index++;
}
```

Comment: `Note:` A few duplicate values when converted to key would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a list for the second map values because some of your values could appear twice and that would result in duplicate keys which maps can't support.

- [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) creates a map using a supplied `key`
- [Collectors.mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) gets the `key` as the value for entry into the value which is a list of doubles.

Try it like this.

```
Map<Double, Integer> map = Map.of(2.0, 1, 3.0, 1, 8.0, 5, 9.0, 7, 4.0, 7);

Map<Integer, List<Double>> keystoV  = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue,
        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println();
keystoV.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
9.0=7
8.0=5
2.0=1
3.0=1
4.0=7

1=[2.0, 3.0]
5=[8.0]
7=[9.0, 4.0]
```

Here is a loop version using the [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method.

- if key is absent, create a list for that key.
- it also returns the list so the new value (old key) many be added to the list.

```
keystoV.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
Map<Integer, List<Double>> result = new HashMap<>();

for(Entry<Double, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
    result.computeIfAbsent(e.getValue(), v->new ArrayList<>()).add(e.getKey());
}

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
1=[2.0, 3.0]
5=[8.0]
7=[9.0, 4.0]
```